# Summation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: summation

Given $2(\sqrt {n+1}- \sqrt{n})<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2(\sqrt {n}- \sqrt {n-1})$, I need to prove that :

$2\sqrt{m} - 2< \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2\sqrt{m} -1$

Attempt at proof: I can prove the Left Hand Side (I think), the Right Hand Side is a problem.

The Left Hand Side:
Since we know that $2(\sqrt {n+1}- \sqrt{n})<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, we can take summation on both sides of the inequality to get:

$2(\sqrt {m+1}- 1)<\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ where we use the telescoping property of the summation. But $2(\sqrt {m}- 1)<2(\sqrt {m+1}- 1)$ and so we  have $2\sqrt{m} - 2< \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

The Right Hand side:
Since we know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2(\sqrt {n}- \sqrt {n-1})$, we proceed by taking summation and using the telescoping propoerty of summation to get:

$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< 2\sqrt{m}$

I am stuck here. How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< 2\sqrt{m}-1$ would also hold?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$S=\sum_{n\leq m}1\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{m}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{m}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t^{3/2}}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and since $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \leq t
 $ we have $$S\leq\sqrt{m}+\int_{1}^{m}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt=\color{red}{2\sqrt{m}-1}$$ as wanted.

Comment: Thanks! But we haven't done Abel Summation. If you could provide an answer based on simple summation properties or/and induction, then I'll be grateful.